# Join with the closest sibling with type = 1

Tags: mysql, join, dql, siblings, closest

I have a table "sf_messages" storing tickets and answers :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sf_messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `answered_by` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_child_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL COMMENT '1 = Question, 2 = Answer',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_C375BE71A5038785` (`last_child_id`),
  KEY `IDX_C375BE71A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_C375BE713948559F` (`answered_by`),
  KEY `IDX_C375BE71727ACA70` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=51740;
```

My front-end users can post a ticket, and my admins can answer them. The owner of this ticket is also able to answer back.

- parent_id is used for children to store the original ticket.
- last_child_id is used for original messages to store the last message in the conversation
- type is used to deifferentiate front-end and back-end messages (1 = front-end, 2  = back-end)
- user_id always store the front-end user of the conversation
- answered_by store the author of the message (front-end user if type = 1, back-end user if type = 2)

So it's like a conversation, with an original ticket, and children messages.

```
- Original ticket (from User 1)
| - Answer #1 (from Admin 1)
| - Answer #2 (from User 1)
| - Answer #3 (from Admin 1)
| - Answer #4 (from User 1)
| - Answer #5 (from Admin 2)
```

For stats purpose, I want to get the average duration between a message from a front-end user, and the answer from an admin, grouped by admin users.

I tried this, but I understand the JOIN is incorrect, because answers are joined on the original message, not the closest message from front-end user.

```
public function fetchTotalAnswerDurationInSecondsByUserInDateRange(\Evo\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null, array $range)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select('SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(m.createdAt, q.createdAt)))')
        ->join('EvoBackendBundle:Message', 'q', 'WITH', 'm.parent = q')
        ->where('m.type = 2')
    ;

    if( !is_null($user) ) {
        $qb->andWhere('m.answeredBy = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user);
    }

    if( $range['start'] ) {
        $qb->andWhere('m.createdAt >= :start')
            ->setParameter('start', $range['start']);
    }

    if( $range['end'] ) {
        $qb->andWhere('m.createdAt <= :end')
            ->setParameter('end', $range['end']);
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

I can differentiate front-end and  back-end messages with "type" field. 1 = front-end message, 2 = back-end message. I guess I also have to deal with something like `WHERE MAX(q.created_at) < m.created_at`, but I dont know how to proceed.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I almost achieved with `SELECT m.*, q.* 
FROM sf_messages m

JOIN (
    SELECT q2.*
    FROM sf_messages q2 
    WHERE q2.type = 1
    ORDER BY q2.created_at DESC
) q ON q.parent_id = m.parent_id


WHERE m.created_at BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-31 23:59:59'
AND m.type = 2
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING MAX(q.created_at) < m.created_at
ORDER BY `m`.`parent_id` ASC`. This query returns me a list of backend messages, with their direct parent. Now, i'd like to group these messages with answered_by field, and compute a SUM of timediff between backend message and its parent.

Comment: I tried adding `SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(m.createdAt, q.createdAt)))` in the SELECT, and GROUP BY m.answered_by, but it returns only 1 row, where I should I have 1 row per backend user (answered_by field)